# How to install JUnit on Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, junit

I followed all the steps from this [tutorial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/85sXm.png)
But still when I run the test it's seems to be some error...

Here's some photo from my computer that my be helpful for you to see what have i done...
[image: The folder where i downloaded junit from http://search.maven.org/#search|gav|1|g:%22junit%22%20AND%20a:%22junit%22]
[image: Createt JUNIT_HOME variable]
[image: Full variable value is: %CLASSPATH%;%JUNIT_HOME%\junit4.10.jar;.;]

Also I copied code from tutorial just for testing and configured build path and added external JARs
[image]
 but when I run it it show check red mark in front of it (so something is wrong) instead of green as in tutorial.
[image]

*Only diferents when I add external JAR and expand Junit libary is little bit diferent on my laptop and in tutorial... In tutoral it looks like this:*
[image]

**Where am I wrong and how to fix error to install JUnit corectly?**

Comment: The error message specifies that what's missing is hamcrest, not Junit. Is hamcrest in the classpath?

Comment: @Loïc It wasn't. Now, when you said I added it, so now my CLASSPATH value is: %CLASSPATH%;%JUNIT_HOME%\junit4.12.jar;C:\Junit4\hamcrest-core-1.3

Is it correct?

Comment: Sorry, it should be added to you "Java Build Path".

Comment: Why dont you make use of eclipse' built in junit? In general, there is no need to add your own junit-libs. If you remove your junit-libs and make use of a junit-annotation, eclipse suggests to add junit to your build-path. If you want to add junit-libraries by yourself to your projects build-path(s), you can achieve that by configuring your projects build-path, switching to libraries and choosing "Add Library...". A new window opens with a set of 'default' libraries. One default-library is JUnit. After selecting this entry and clicking "Next", you can choose the junit-version you want to use.